# Service values resetting to default?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I swear I've done this before, but I'm banging my head against the wall here and can't figure out what's wrong. Is my controller not making the updates to the service, or is the service resetting with each controller init?

I load my service with a default value.

```
angular.module('app')
 .service('Config', function () {
  this.name = 'John Doe';
});
```

In my controller, I call the service.

```
angular.module('app')
 .controller('TestCtrl', function (Config) {
  var self = this; 
  self.name = Config.name;
});
```

My view would look like the below. The service value and controller value (the same) appear to be updated in the scope, but like I said, I lose the new value on route change. Any ideas!! This is awful.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="test.name">
```

Comment: Your model is bound to `test.name`. When a new value is assigned by the `ngModelController`, the previous reference to `Config.name` is broken.

Comment: No, it's plain old JavaScript references

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this

```
var a = { name: 'foo' };
var b = { name: a.name };
```

Right now, `b.name` is also "foo" as you would imagine. Now, if I execute

```
b.name = 'bar';
```

Now, `b.name` is "bar" however `a.name` will still be "foo".

---

If you want to maintain the value in your service, you'll have to use that in your `ng-model`.

```
.controller('TestCtrl', function(Config) {
    this.config = Config;
});
```

and

```
<input type="text" ng-model="test.config.name">
```